# Subgraphs with diameter 2

Tags: graph-theory, mathematica, clustering

When examining the modularity of graphs or networks, concepts like "[blocks](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ebrian/780/bibliography/04%20Blockmodels/Holland%20-%201983%20-%20Stochastic%20blockmodels,%20first%20steps.pdf)", "clusters", or "communities" are used, more or less strictly defined as (maximal) subgraphs with some given properties.

A natural generalization of cliques (as maximal *complete* subgraphs, having diameter 1) would be "**diam-k-cliques**", i.e. maximal subgraphs with diameter k. Under which name are such graphs filed and can be googled? And which efficient methods to find them are there - or some statistics on them? Is there a Mathematica function for it?

To make "diam-2-cliques" more community-like one might add the simple requirement that the minimal degree of such a subgraph must be 2 (to avoid star graphs as "communities").

Comment: Instead of a "clique", search for "plex" or "club". These type of concepts appear in social network analysis. I think the authors there usually twist the definition of a k-clique to something quite different and it's quite annoying.

Comment: yes, "clubs" and "clans" are the terms used to capture diameter properties in communities / clusters. There are two types, because one defines diameter in terms of longest pairwise distance when the path is allowed to use vertices external to the community, or the other version where the paths which determine the diameter must remain interior to the community.